# iPad orientation returns unknown values

Tags: ipad

I use this code:

`UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];`

to get iPad orientation but it returns UIDeviceOrientationUnknown when I use OpenGL rendering. When I play movies or I display UIViews it return the correct value. Do you know how may I get correct orientation? I don't want to use the accelerometer because I want to know when the device has locked orientation.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know how may I get the lock orientation button state?

Comment: Don't bother with the lock orientation button. That is no longer a feature in iOS 4.2.

Comment: @Evan: Yes it is, it’s just moved from the hardware switch to the software. Read literally any review of iOS 4.2.

Comment: @Jeff: Yes, you will still be able to lock the orientation via the multitasking bar. The orientation lock button will be a mute switch. However, there is no API for determining whether the orientation lock switch is on or off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I add [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications]; the orientation will be correct even in OpenGL rendering mode. UIDeviceOrientationUnknown orientation is sometimes returned but only for short time.

Answer (score 22):

There are situations where the accelerometer can’t get an accurate read on the orientation, such as when the device is held flat. You should still be able to get the current orientation using:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

Comment: Event if I hold the device in a normal position the orientation is UIDeviceOrientationUnknown, but ONLY when I use OpenGL rendering. I hide the status bar and it's orientation is always portrait.

Answer (score 14):

In iOS 13, the `statusBarOrientation` has been deprecated.  The new preferred way of getting this orientation is

`let orientation = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation`